# SuperDraco Dragon V2 vs Merlin 1D Falcon

Tags: spacex, merlin-1d, super-draco

I figured out that ten SuperDraco engines have about the same thrust as a Merlin 1D. So if we replace Falcon 9's second stage with a Dragon V2 with 2 additional SuperDracos ( and replace some seats with fuel tanks,) can it plus a Falcon first stage propel itself into orbit?(or, at least, sub-orbit.) 
Plus, Dragon V2 is reusable, while a Falcon second stage is not. So I think replace a Falcon 9 second stage with a Dragon is pretty cost-saving, huh?

Answer (score 8):

The thrust of the engines (for any launcher or spacecraft, really) is nowhere near as important as the amount of fuel feeding them.

It takes about 9400-10000m/s of [∆v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v), depending on trajectory, to reach stable orbit from Earth's surface.

The second stage of a Falcon 9 1.1, depending on payload, is responsible for the majority of that speed: 6200-6700 m/s. That gets 10-13 tons into LEO. It achieves this by carrying [92 tons](http://www.spaceflight101.com/falcon-9-v11.html) of propellants.

According to the numbers filed with the EPA, [Dragon V2 carries 450 gallons of hydrazine and NTO propellants](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/33f75a/just_how_much_deltav_will_the_dragon_2_capsule/cqkecfj), roughly *2* tons. With the dry mass of 4.2 tons, that's about 900 m/s delta-V assuming zero payload. With 3 tons of payload you've got about 565 m/s.

On the up side, losing the second stage means the first stage is carrying much less weight, so it gets you going a lot faster, yielding an extra 3200m/s of ∆v, but that leaves you 2000 m/s short of orbit.

Replacing the Dragon payload with fuel tankage could get the total system ∆v to 8800m/s, still 1000m/s short of orbit with no useful payload.

Answer (score 5):

The critical number for rocket engines is their specific impulse (Isp, a measure of how efficient the engine is).

- The Merlin has an Isp of [311 s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merlin_%28rocket_engine_family%29).
- The SuperDraco Isp is [estimated](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/26o6du/spacex_superdraco_thruster_firing/) to be around 225 s (which is in line with other [hydrazine engines](http://www.astronautix.com/props/hydazine.htm)).

This means an upper stage that uses SuperDracos would need to be much heavier than a Merlin-powered upper stage, because it'd need more fuel to achieve the same $\Delta V$. So you'd end up replacing the second stage with a Dragon that's larger and heavier than the second stage (and as a consequence, will be harder to land intact).

Comment: The thing is that, the SuperDracos only need to lift the Dragon, while the Merlin Vacuum need to lift the Dragon AND the second stage

Comment: No, the SuperDracos need to lift the Dragon PLUS all of the fuel. It turns out, to carry all that fuel, you need a structure the size of the second stage. The Dragon carries enough fuel to fire the SuperDracos for a few seconds. You need to run them for ~8 minutes to get to orbit.